# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory ,even I have the image in that particular folder

Tags: python

I am a newbie to python. I am trying to put my 22k images into matrix before i process them using CNN. However, I encounter this situation which I don't know where I did wrong.

```
path1 = 'C:/Users/Z/Documents/Python Scripts/Data'
path2 = 'C:/Users/Z/Documents/Python Scripts/Data1'
listing = os.listdir(path1) 
num_samples=size(listing)

for file in listing:
    im = Image.open(path1 + '\\' + file)  
    img_rows, img_cols = 224, 224
    img = im.resize((img_rows,img_cols),3)        
    img.save(path2 +'\\' + file, "JPEG")


imlist = os.listdir(path2)

img_data_list=[]
a = Image.open('Data1' + '\\'+ imlist[0]) # open one image to get size
im1 = array(a)
m,n = im1.shape[0:3] # get the size of the images
imnbr = len(imlist) # get the number of images
num_samples = len(imlist)
```

I got this error

[image]

Comment: what os are you using? windows?

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: See my answer, if it helps mark it accepted ;) @Tan Ying Ying

Comment: You are referencing a partial filepath - you have path1 and path2 predefined, but then you only use 'Data1' as a string in your 5th line from bottom. `a = ...` Change that line to include the full path. The error is pretty self-explanatory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path is incorrect when you open the single image, it should be:

```
a = Image.open(path2 + '\\'+ imlist[0])
```

Comment: Thank you, I dint realized.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = Image.open(path2 + '\\'+ imlist[0])
```

You just had a small code error. `"Data1"` that isn't a correct path

Answer (score 0):

`a = Image.open('Data1' + '\\'+ imlist[0]) # open one image to get size`

You are supposed to read from path2. aren't you??